# How to print a string that is sent as a parameter to class method in smalltalk

Tags: oop, smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to write a class method which recieves a string and prints it.
I've tried this:

```
log: aMessage
Transcript show: aMessage; cr.
```

and tried to use it as follows:

```
ContractObject log: 'aaa'.
```

(ContractObject is the name of class) but it didn't work.
I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that it's a dynamic language and that it's not known that it's a string.
I tried to convert it etc. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

No, types are definitely not the problem here. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What was the error message you got? Did you get any at all?

Do you have the Transcript open? If it's not open you wont see anything. You can open it programmatically by evaluating `Transcript open` or manually by using the menu.

Also, make sure that you have implemented `#log:` on the *class side* (that's what you see when you click the `class` button in the code browser).